# When to use ng-view (with a router) or a custom directive to display templates(partials)?

Tags: angularjs-directive, ng-view, angular-template

I'm new to AngularJS and would definitely benefit from experient AngularJS developers! So here you go :

In AngularJS what is the difference in terms of performance of using ng-view (with router) or a custom directive to display templates (HTML partials) ?

How big **should** be a custom directive ? From what I see a custom directive could substitute a view entirely but **should it be used that way** ? There might be benefits and drawbacks using one or the other.

What would the be the rules of thumb to use one or the other ?

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I think the performance aspect of the question is kinda a moot point.  Let's use the idea of a table and a number of table rows. Unless you're generating 100s of rows of data utilizing custom directives or loading template, you're probably not going to incur any noticeable performance penalty.  Angular caches templates so it's not like it's loading the same template over and over for each row.  If you are generating large number of rows, then there are performance tweaks and different UX approaches you can utilize to address those issues (e.g. `track by` for `ng-repeat`, endless scroll, pagination, etc.)

> How big **should** be a custom directive?

As you stated, you could use a directive to make an entire view.  I think in Angular 1.*, that was not its intended functionality.  A directive was more like a widget or UI Component (for those directives that are mostly UI containers with specific UX in mind, we're not considering non-UI type directives in this discussion obviously).

My rule of thumb is this:

- If the UI in question has some ownership of a URL (aka. route) then treat it as a view.  Generally a URL is unique visually speaking, so directive-ifing it will only create more work and little pay off.
- If the UI in question works more like a widget/uicomponent, then use a directive.
- If the UI in question is going to be reused over and over (e.g. inside `ng-repeat`) then a directive should be considered if isolating certain *work* on data it is consuming will be performed.

All of these points get complicated by the intended UX. But the rule of thumb provides a good starting point.

Keep in mind, Angular 2 is going to change all of this up by nixing scope and treating directives more like views.